# When does decompression process take place and how does solidbreak flag really work in Inno Setup?

Tags: compression, inno-setup

There's such a thing in Inno Setup as `SolidCompression` and there's a flag used in the `[Files]` section, which is `solidbreak`. Could anybody explain to me how does the aforementioned flag work, when do we really need to use it and when does the decompression process take place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solid compression means that the files are compressed as though all the files were just one big file. This usually results in better compression because compression knowledge built during one file will be carried over to the next, instead of a restart. The downside is that in order to decompress a specific file during installation, one has to decompress all the files before it.

The `solidbreak` flag, when applied, tells the compression engine to split up the solid compression and start a new stream when it comes to the source the flag is applied to, so that if that file specifically needs to be decompressed, the decompression code can simply seek to the position in the file where it starts. Basically, the downside from above disappears, but then some of the bonus of that compression knowledge gets lost as well.

If you want to use solid compression, and you have the sort of files that you have to install all of them, don't use `solidbreak`, but if you have a list of checkboxes to select modules, you *might* want to consider applying `solidbreak` to some or all of the optional modules. If you don't, all the files will be decompressed even though only one some are needed for the selectedd options. The exact result will vary with file size and so on so I can't say more than that you might have to experiment to see the results.